# strings returned by find gets separated in the middle

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to shell (bash) script. On terminal, `find` behaves as:

```
find . -name 'Ado*'
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz002.jpg
```

However, my shell script seems to separate the file name by the space after "Adobe".

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
for base_name in `find . -name "Ado*"`
do
echo $base_name
 :
i=$((i+1))
done
```

It returns something like:

```
./Adobe
ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg
 :
```

What's wrong where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the answers so far have used `find ... | while read ...` which works, but the while loop runs in a subshell (because it's part of a pipeline), and so your count of files ($i) is lost when the subshell exits.  If you're using bash (i.e. your shebang *must* be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`), you can use its process substitution feature to avoid this problem:

```
i=1
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d '' base_name; do
    echo "$base_name"
    :
    i=$((i+1))
done 3< <(find . -name "Ado*" -print0)
```

I've also added some other tricks here to make this more robust: I set IFS to null (just for the read command) so it won't trim leading or trailing whitespace from filenames; I use read's `-r` option so it won't do funny things with backslashes in filenames; I use find's `-print0` and read's `-d ''` to use null bytes as the file delimiter, so it won't even be confused by linefeeds in filenames; I use double-quotes around `$base_name` inside the loop, so it won't get split on whitespace there either (not important for echo, but it'll matter if you actually try to use the filenames as filenames); finally, I pass the file list via fd #3 instead of #0 (stdin) with `3<` and read's `-u3` option, so in case anything inside the loop reads from stdin it won't accidentally inhale a pile of filenames.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name 'Ado*'
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz002.jpg
```

The `find` result contains `white-spaces`.
So the following `for loop` iterate over `4` items.

You can change the script to:

```
i=1
find . -name 'Ado*' | while read base_name
do
    echo $base_name
    :
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your shell script.

When you call a program between back quotes the command is executed in a forked process, and the result is returned to the main program to be lexed and parsed. And as a string the result is separated into several token.

You should use read builtin like that

```
#! /bin/sh
i=0
find . -name 'Ado*' | while read result
do
echo $result
i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shell replaces `for base_name in $(find . -name "Ado*")` by
`for base_name in ./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg ./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz002.jpg`

Therefore, `for` *sees* four words:
- `./Adobe` 
- `ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg` 
- `./Adobe` 
- `ReaderScreenSnapz002.jpg`

My advice: replace `for base_name in` by `while read base_name`

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
find . -name "Ado*" |
while read base_name
do
echo $base_name
 :
i=$((i+1))
done
```

`read` reads line after line and stops the `while` loop at the end of its input (`find`).
`read` stores each line in `base_name` variable.

Comment: Note that this will break on files which have a newline in their name (which is uncommon but possible). If this has a chance of happening, you should either use `find`'s `print0` action along with `xargs -0`, or use directly `find`'s `exec` action.