# sed result differs b/w command line & shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

The following `sed` command from commandline returns what I expect.

```
$ echo './Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg' | sed -e 's/.*\./After-1\./' 
After-1.jpg             <--- result
```

Howerver, in the following bash script, `sed` seeems not to act as I expect.

```
#!/bin/bash
beforeNamePrefix=$1
i=1
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d '' base_name; do
    echo $base_name
    rename=`(echo ${base_name} | sed -e s/.*\./After-$i./g)`
    echo 'Renamed to ' $rename
    i=$((i+1))
done 3< <(find . -name "$beforeNamePrefix*" -print0)
```

Result (with several files with similar names in the same directory):

```
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz001.jpg
Renamed to  After-1.         <--- file extension is missing.
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz002.jpg
Renamed to  After-2.
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz003.jpg
Renamed to  After-3.
./Adobe ReaderScreenSnapz004.jpg
Renamed to  After-4.
```

Where am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your `sed` command is not the same in both versions.

Comment: OOC, why are you using fd 3 instead of stdin?

Comment: @SiegeX: He's using my [answer to his earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145760/bash-script-strings-returned-by-find-gets-separated-in-the-middle/9147793#9147793); I habitually use fd 3 just in case something inside the loop decides to read from stdin (usually with hilarious results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **Parameter Expansion**

```
#!/bin/bash
beforeNamePrefix="$1"
i=1
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d '' base_name; do
    echo "$base_name"
    rename="After-$((i++)).${base_name##*.}"
    echo "Renamed to $rename"
done 3< <(find . -name "$beforeNamePrefix*" -print0)
```

I also fixed some quoting to prevent unwanted word splitting

Answer (score 4):

You have omitted the single quotes around the program in your script. Without quoting, the shell will strip the backslash from `.*\.` yielding a regular expression with quite a different meaning.  (You will need double quotes in order for the substitution to work, though. You can mix single and double quotes `'s/.*\./'"After-$i./"` or just add enough backslashes to escape the escaped escape sequence (sic).